# How to add an if statement in a DAX formula measure?

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I am new to DAX and have created two measures to get the total pay per employee then lookup that total pay into a table and return a value in my Power Pivot.

**Total Pay Measure:**

```
NMRPaySum:=SUMX(Pay,[Regular Pay]+[Overtime Pay]+[Other Pay])
```

**Range Lookup Measure:**

```
SSSContributionEE :=
CALCULATE (
    VALUES ( SSSContribution[EE] ),
    FILTER (
        SSSContribution,
        [NMRPaySum] >= SSSContribution[Lower Bound] &&
        [NMRPaySum] <= SSSContribution[Upper Bound]
    )
)
```

However, I need the range lookup to only calculate if the employee type is satisfied.

**The logic for it is below:**

```
If Employee[Type]="Regular" Then
    Calculate SSSConbtributionEE
Else
    0
End If
```

**I have tried this DAX formula, but doesn't seem to be working:**

```
=
IF (
    OR ( Salary[Type] = "Regular", Salary[Type] = "Agency" ),
    CALCULATE (
        VALUES ( SSSContribution[EE] ),
        FILTER (
            SSSContribution,
            [NMRPaySum] >= SSSContribution[Lower Bound] &&
            [NMRPaySum] <= SSSContribution[Upper Bound]
        )
    ),
    0
)
```

**NMRPay Table:**
[image]

**SSS Contribution Table:**

[image]

**Employee Information Table:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use your measure as is, for all the data. You then build a Pivot table, where you can use a filter or slicers on Employee Type to exclude unwanted values. Add the measure to the Values area and it will only calculate for data that is in the rows and columns of the pivot table.

Comment: I would like to add some kind of "safety" or error prevention to it as well in case the employee doesn't traditionally use filters and slicers, because we'll end up losing more money if they make a mistake and forget to filter for instance so I was hoping to make sure it ends up 0. And based on my experience our employees are extremely careless and not tech savy so I wouldn't risk it

Answer (score 0):

For the `OR` condition, you should be able to add that as another filter:

```
=  CALCULATE (
        VALUES ( SSSContribution[EE] ),
        FILTER (
            SSSContribution,
            [NMRPaySum] >= SSSContribution[Lower Bound] &&
            [NMRPaySum] <= SSSContribution[Upper Bound]
        ),
        FILTER (Salary, Salary[Type] = "Regular" || SalaryType = "Agency")
)
```

This may or may not work depending on your exact data model / relationship structure, but it might point you in the right direction. It's possible you need to use `RELATED` / `RELATEDTABLE`, but I'm not sure without being able to play with it myself.

Comment: Updated the main post to include the table structures. Thanks will try this out!